# Модальное окно bootstrap + контроллер

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, bootstrap4

подскажите пожалуйста, как мне подвязать модальное окно к каждому пользователю из списка. код прилагается.p.s обычная кнопка удаления норм работает, а с модальным окном разобраться не могу.

```
<div class="col-12">
            <form action="/admin/panel" method="get">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Имя</th>
                        <th scope="col">email</th>
                        <th scope="col">roles</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="user : ${userlist}">
                        <td th:utext="${user.id}"></td>
                        <td th:utext="${user.name}">...</p></td>
                        <td th:utext="${user.email}">...</p></td>
                        <td th:utext="${user.roles}">...</p></td>
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <form action="/admin/panel/addUser" method="post" name="id" th:value="${user.id}">
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editor">Edit</button></td>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="editor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <strong>Username</strong>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${user.name}">
                                        <strong>Email</strong>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${user.email}">
                                        <strong>Roles</strong>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${user.roles}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="id" th:value="${user.id}">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        <form action="/admin/panel/deleteUser" method="post" th:value="${user.id}" name="id">
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleter">Delete</button></td>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deleter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleterTitle">Delete user</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <strong>ID</strong>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${userID}" readonly>
                                            <strong>Username</strong>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${name}" readonly>
                                            <strong>Email</strong>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${email}" readonly>
                                            <strong>Roles</strong>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:placeholder="${roles}" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Вот контроллер вызывающий всех юзеров:

```
@GetMapping("/panel")
public String getUsers(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userlist", userService.getAllUsers());
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("role", user.getRoles());
    return "admin/panel";
}
```

И контроллер удаления соответственно

```
 @PostMapping("/panel/deleteUser")
public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("userID", userService.findOne(id).getId());
    model.addAttribute("name", userService.findOne(id).getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("email", userService.findOne(id).getEmail());
    model.addAttribute("roles", userService.findOne(id).getAuthorities());
    userService.deleteById(id);
    return "redirect:/admin/panel";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено: сделал динамический id через шаблонизатор thymeleaf

```
<form action="/admin/panel/editUser" method="post">
                                            <td>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" th:data-target="${'#edituser'+user.id}">
                                                Edit
                                            </button>

                                                <!-- Edit Modal -->
                                                <div class="modal fade" th:id="${'edituser'+user.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
```